# Vue File Agent from CDN on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I'm setting up my first ever ASP.NET MVC server and teaching myself how to use it for a particular project I'm working on.

I have a couple of controller "endpoints" set up and working wonderfully for HTTP `POST` requests but, as a "tangential" part of this project, I would like to have the controller serve up a page with a file upload form.

Specifically, I'd *really* like to use the [Vue File Agent](https://safrazik.github.io/vue-file-agent/), preferably implemented using the [CDN distribution method](https://github.com/safrazik/vue-file-agent#installation:%7E:text=or%20with%20script%20tag,-%3C!%2D%2D%20jsdelivr%20cdn%20%2D%2D%3E) because I'd rather not install additional components on the server for this one little thing if I can get away with it.

I'm not new to ASP.NET, HTML, or CSS (and even limited JavaScript), but I *am* unfamiliar with using ASP.NET MVC controllers and views to serve page(s). As stated, I've figured out how to use the controllers to handle the `POST` requests I'm generating from other systems.

Also, I have a "basic" understanding of how the view works and I've got the controller serving up an HTML file. However, when I try to include the Vue File Agent component via the CDN, I'm not getting anything.

I've tried a variety of different Vue File Agent samples just to get *something* on the page, including the [Gmail Inspired Demo](https://codepen.io/safrazik/pen/OJLgvya) on CodePen, but I must be missing something because I can't get the actual "sample" to show up and it seems to be totally ignoring all of the CSS styling.

[image: Screenshot from MVC]

In my controller, I have this:

```vb
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

And my `Index.vbhtml` file looks like this:

```html
@Code
    Layout = Nothing
End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Insurance Submission Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-file-agent@latest/dist/vue-file-agent.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-file-agent@latest/dist/vue-file-agent.umd.js"></script>
    <style>
        .vfa-demo {
            position: relative;
        }

            .vfa-demo .file-preview-wrapper::before {
                background: transparent;
            }

            .vfa-demo .file-row {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 15;
                line-height: 24px;
                text-align: left;
                background: #EEE;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                padding: 2px 5px;
            }

            .vfa-demo .remove {
                float: right;
                margin-top: -3px;
            }

            .vfa-demo .progress {
                float: right;
                width: 85px;
                height: 10px;
                margin-top: 7px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                background: #FFF;
                border: 1px solid #AAA;
            }

                .vfa-demo .progress.completed {
                    display: none;
                }

            .vfa-demo .drop-help-text {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                margin: 2px;
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
                z-index: 1200;
                font-size: 32px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #888;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                display: none;
            }

            .vfa-demo .is-drag-over .drop-help-text {
                display: flex;
            }

            .vfa-demo .upload-block {
                border: 2px dashed transparent;
                padding: 20px;
                padding-top: 0;
            }

            .vfa-demo .is-drag-over.upload-block {
                border-color: #AAA;
            }

            .vfa-demo .vue-file-agent {
                border: 0 !important;
                box-shadow: none !important;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="vue-file-agent-demo">
        <div class="vfa-demo bg-light pt-3">
            <VueFileAgent class="upload-block"
                          ref="vfaDemoRef"
                          :uploadUrl="'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5d4fb20b3000005c111099e3'"
                          :uploadHeaders="{}"
                          :multiple="true"
                          :deletable="true"
                          :theme="'list'"
                          :maxSize="'25MB'"
                          :errorText="{
        size: 'This file is too large to be attached',
      }"
                          v-model="fileRecords">
                <template v-slot:before-outer>
                    <p>Email Attachment example with drag & drop support and <span class="badge">attachment</span> keyword basic detection.</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="John Doe">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" value="johndoe@example.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea v-model="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:file-preview="slotProps">
                    <div :key="slotProps.index" class="grid-box-item file-row">
                        <button type="button" class="close remove" aria-label="Remove" v-on:click="removeFileRecord(slotProps.fileRecord)">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="progress" :class="{'completed': slotProps.fileRecord.progress() == 100}">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" :style="{width: slotProps.fileRecord.progress() + '%'}"></div>
                        </div>
                        <strong>{{ slotProps.fileRecord.name() }}</strong> <span class="text-muted">({{ slotProps.fileRecord.size() }})</span>
                    </div>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:file-preview-new>
                    <div class="text-left my-3" key="new">
                        <a href="#" class="">Select files</a> or drag & drop here
                    </div>
                </template>
                <!--       <template v-slot:after-inner>
                        <div class="text-left pt-1">
                          <a href="#" class="">Select files</a> or drag & drop here
                        </div>
                      </template > -->
                <template v-slot:after-outer>
                    <div title="after-outer">
                        <div class="drop-help-text">
                            <p>Drop here</p>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="send()">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </VueFileAgent>
        </div>
    </script>

    <!-- ----------------------------- -->

    <div class="container py-3">
        <div id="app">

            <h5><a target="_blank" href="https://safrazik.github.io/vue-file-agent">Vue File Agent</a> Playground</h5>

            <hr>

            <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-2">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a target="_blank" class="nav-link" href="https://codepen.io/safrazik/pen/BaBVNEE">1. Preloading Exising Demo</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a target="_blank" class="nav-link" href="https://codepen.io/safrazik/pen/BaBpYme">2. Profile Picture Demo</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a target="_blank" class="nav-link active" href="https://codepen.io/safrazik/pen/OJLgvya">3. Gmail Inspired Demo</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <hr>

            <vue-file-agent-demo></vue-file-agent-demo>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var component = {
            data: function () {
                return {
                    fileRecords: [],
                    message: 'I am sending you the attachments',
                }
            },
            methods: {
                removeFileRecord: function (fileRecord) {
                    return this.$refs.vfaDemoRef.removeFileRecord(fileRecord);
                },
                send: function () {
                    if (this.message.indexOf('attachment') !== -1 && this.fileRecords.length < 1) {
                        if (!confirm('You have mentioned about attachments in your message. Are you sure to send without attachments?')) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    alert('Message sent!');
                }
            }
        }

        component.template = '#vue-file-agent-demo';

        Vue.component('vue-file-agent-demo', component);

        new Vue({
            el: '#app'
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using various other different upload "templates" I've found with varying degrees of success, but I feel I'm still failing to understand some key concepts of working with ASP.NET MVC controllers and views.

For one thing, in the `<template v-slot:file-preview="slotProps">` and `<template v-slot:after-outer>` blocks of the code above, the CodePen has the `<button>` elements defined with `@click="somefunctionname()"`.

However, when I publish these, the server returns an error indicating that `'click' is not declared` (*IntelliSense also reports the same error in the Visual Studio IDE*). I found some other examples using Vue that showed what appears to be the same basic functionality written as `v-on:click="somefunctionname()"`, so I tried that (*as I have listed above*), but I'm still getting nothing.

I'm obviously not understanding how the syntax should be working here, and I'm sure it's "simply" a matter of finding the *right* documentation, but I'd really like to understand the ASP.NET MVC view a little better and figure this out, not only because I want to get this "pretty" upload working, but because I really want to get a better handle on how to use this technology.

What is it that I'm doing wrong and how can I get this functionality working on my ASP.NET MVC controller? How do I define these `@` directives in an ASP.NET MVC view without causing the compiler to freak out (*I had the same issue with some of these `@` directives in a CSS `<style>` block, so it's clearly something I'm going to need to deal with*)?

---

### EDIT

So, as I sorta mentioned above, I've been testing by publishing the site to my web server and viewing the site via the public DNS name. Just to see if I would get anything different, I tried running the site from the Visual Studio debugger.

Interestingly, when I did this, the IDE broke with an exception in my `_Layout.vbhtml`:

```html
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required:=False)
```

Looking at my site's directory structure, there *is no* `~\bundles\` directory. Digging around a little, I found all of the jQuery and Bootstrap files located in the `~\Scripts\` directory, so I simply removed the two calls to the `@Scripts.Render()` method (leaving the call to `@RenderSection()`) and tried again. This time, I didn't get the exception, so I went ahead and published again to test. Unfortunately, I got the same results as what I posted in my screenshot, so that doesn't appear to be the source of my "issue", but I thought I'd mention it here, just in case it helps to point me in the right direction.

As I said at the beginning of my question, this is my first time setting up an ASP.NET MVC server, so I've not done much in the way of customization or modification to the base template from Visual Studio apart from creating a new controller and associated view and adding a couple of things to the `web.config` / `global.asax` to handle some of the other functionality I'm implementing. Perhaps there's something I *should* have done, but I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally figured out at least *part* of my problem, and it's because I'm a moron. I stumbled across it when I opened up my browser's "Developer Tools" and drilled down through a few screens. Apparently, I was missing a pretty important piece of the Vue puzzle in my HTML. Once I added *this* line to my `<head>` (*the "core" Vue library*):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

I finally got a visible upload box. It's still missing all the nice-looking styling, but at least the control is there now and I can start working with it a little more.
[image: Working Vue File Agent]